# Java: Premature EOF error when reading lines from webpage

Tags: java, web-crawler, ioexception

I am iterating through webpages line-by-line and sometimes get `java.io.IOException: Premature EOF`. I have seen reports of people getting this error from reading characters, but not whole lines, so I'm not sure what to do to get rid of this.

The stack trace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:565)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:609)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:696)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3336)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at crawler.Crawler.crawl(SEC_Crawler.java:63)
```

And the code that causes it is:

```
 for (String webpage_address : Webpages) {
        URL filing = new URL(webpage_address);
        BufferedReader read_filing = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(filing.openStream()));

        for (String line = read_filing.readLine(); line != null; line = read_filing.readLine()) {
            // Process line
        }
}
```

Comment: The server is sending invalid chunking data, or prematurely terminating the connection. Nothing you can do about it at this end except grin and bear it.